# Single mmap pointer for different types

Tags: c, mmap

I want to use mmap to share multiple global variables of different types between child processes. Do I have to create a different mmap for each type or can I make a struct that holds them all as the mmap pointer?

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to use a structure. mmap uses the CPU's segmentation hardware to map the file into memory, and that hardware works with chunks of memory that are at least one virtual memory page in size; so using many of them when you could just use one is wasteful and slower.

Check that your hardware and your calls to mmap() can map the file at the same address in all processes, if you want to store any pointers in the mapped region. There is no guarantee that the same address will be allocated in all processes, unless you force the issue by using MAP_FIXED.

If you haven't written a concurrent application before, you may have a lot to learn. Memory reads and writes are not necessarily atomic, well-ordered or consistent. Use volatile. Use semaphores. Expect pain.